# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm cannot be cast

Tags: java, database, jsp, struts, actionform

I want to search the data from jsp form in database and display it in another jsp file...

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm cannot be cast to org.mat.search.SearchFB
org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

**SearchFB.java**

```
import org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm;

public class SearchFB extends DynaValidatorForm {

private String userName;
private String caste[];
private String qualification[];
private Integer age;
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
    .
    .
```

**SearchAction.java**

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    SearchFB sfb = (SearchFB) form;
    Formdata fd = new Formdata();
    fd.setUserName((String) sfb.get("userName"));
    fd.setAge((Integer) sfb.get("age"));
    fd.setQualification((String)sfb.get("qualification"));
    fd.setCaste((String) sfb.get("caste"));

    SearchDTO sdto = new SearchDTO();
    SearchJB sjb = new SearchJB();
    sjb.searchProduct(sdto);
    return mapping.findForward("ssuccess");
}
}
```

**Formdata.java**

```
public Formdata extends ActionForm{        
private String userName;
private String qualification;
private Integer age;
private String caste;


public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
    setters and getters...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `DynaValidatorForm` then it should be cast to the action form provided by Struts. For example

```
DynaValidatorForm sfb = (DynaValidatorForm) form;
```

It will solve your class cast exception, but the instances you pass as a parameter to the other layers are not initialized, so the action itself is suspicious.